# How to deploy markshust/docker-magento image to AWS

Tags: magento2, aws, docker

I'm running a project locally using [markshust/docker-magento](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento), and everything is working fine.

Now I need to deploy my store to an AWS cluster using docker, but in my code, I'm not able to see the docker images.

What is the best way to deploy the docker image to AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Mark here, the creator of docker-magento.

I don't have any specific advice here unfortunately, other than that you'll probably want to run Kubernetes along with a proper production deployment strategy, as docker-magento was meant purely for development reasons.

Damien from Graycore has done some extensive work in this area, so I'd recommend reaching out to him: https://twitter.com/damienwebdev